# How to crawl a site and parse only pages that match a RegEx using Scrapy 0.24

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy 0.24 on Python 2.7.9 on a Windows 64-bit machine. I'm trying to tell scrapy to start at a specific URL `http://www.allen-heath.com/products/` and from there only gather data from pages where the url includes the string `ahproducts`.

Unfortunately, when I do this no data is scraped at all. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code below. If there's more information I can provide to help with an answer, please ask and I'll make an edit.

Here is a pastebin of my crawler log: http://pastebin.com/C2QC23m3.

Thank you.

```
import scrapy
import urlparse

from allenheath.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class productsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "products"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.allen-heath.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allen-heath.com/products/"
    ]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['ahproducts']), 'parse')]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html'):
            item = ProductItem()
            item['model'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['itemcode'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['shortdesc'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h3::text').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent').extract()
            item['series'] = sel.css('#pagestrip > div > div > a:nth-child(3)::text').extract()
            item['imageorig'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent .col-sm-9 img').xpath('./@src').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url) for url in item['image_urls']]
            yield item
```

After some suggestions from eLRuLL here is my updated spider file. I've modified the start_url to include a page that has links that include "ahproducts" in their URL. My original code didn't have any matching URLs on the start page.

**products.py**

```
import scrapy
import urlparse

from allenheath.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class productsSpider(scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = "products"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.allen-heath.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allen-heath.com/key-series/ilive-series/ilive-remote-controllers/"
    ]
    rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(allow='.*ahproducts.*'),
                callback='parse_item'
                ),
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html'):
            item = ProductItem()
            item['model'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['itemcode'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['shortdesc'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h3::text').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent').extract()
            item['series'] = sel.css('#pagestrip > div > div > a:nth-child(3)::text').extract()
            item['imageorig'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent .col-sm-9 img').xpath('./@src').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url) for url in item['image_urls']]
            yield item
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to use rules you need to use `scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider` not `scrapy.Spider`.

Then, change the name of your method to something like `parse_item` not `parse` and also update your rules like:

```
 rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow='.*ahproducts.*'),
            callback='parse_item'
        ),
    )
```

The `parse` method is always called as a response for the `start_urls` requests.

Finally only change the `allowed_domains` to `allowed_domains = ["allen-heath.com"]`

P.D. To crawl different levels of the site with rules, you need to specify which links to follow and which links to to parse, something like this:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=('some link to follow')
        ),
        follow=True,
    ),
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=('some link to parse')
        ),
        callback='parse_method',
    ),
)
```

Comment: The pages with URLs that match `ahproducts` are linked on pages that start with `http://www.allen-heath.com/series/` or `/key-series/`. Pages you can only get to by starting at `http://www.allen-heath.com/products/`. I was under the incorrect impression that scrapy would follow the links on `http://www.allen-heath.com/products/` until it found pages that matched `ahproducts`. So if I'm understand it right, using rules, scrapy will only match and gather data from links that match my rule AND exist on my `start_url`. In that case I suppose I will need to generate MANY `start_url`s first?

Comment: Per your comment, I've gone ahead and changed `class productsSpider(scrapy.Spider)` to `class productsSpider(scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider):` And I'm using a start_url that DOES have links with `ahproducts` in it. But it's still not pulling any data at all.

Comment: also, check that you need to change your method name from `parse` to `parse_item`, to check that is working.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This worked out for me and it grabs all of the data I expect. Just a couple questions for clarification. In your post you said "P.D.", what does that stand for? And secondly, for the `allowed_domains` you dropped the `http://www.`. I assume the reason for that was to account for links that use `https://`? And lastly, in your first code block the callback is `parse_item`, but then in your second code block you used `parse_method`. I'm using the latter and it works fine. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: @jimmykup , about the `parse_*` methods, you can call it whatever you want, but the `parse` method is always called after start_requests (the method the calls the start_urls). PD=postdata sorry about that.